# How to replace the text contents of an XML element with the contents of another generic text?

Tags: xml, perl

I work with data from an aircraft manufacturer B. I need to provide this data to a third party in order for them to develop tools that can manipulate it.
The catch is that the data needs to be anonymized as we have a confidentiality agreement in place with B. So whenever we have an element like

```
<element>Some really sensitive information</element>
```

We need to replace the text content with non-sensitive content.
I can do it, with a perl one-liner, to the extent of replacing all alphanumeric characters with *.

```
perl -ne 'if(/<(PARA)>([^<]*)<\/PARA>(.*)/){$tag = $1;$content = $2; $content =~ s/\S/*/g;print "<".$tag.">".$content."</".$tag.">".$3."\n"}else{print $_;}' infile > outfile
```

However, because I'd like to to make the anaonymized data more readable, and related tools more troubleshootable, I'd like to insert "real" text instead of the *, with the caveat being that the entrie text content needs to be the same length. No problem about individual words changing length but the overall text content must have the same length.

So the result would be a "lorem ipsum" type thing.

One drawback to this is that I'd then end up with all `<title>` elements, for example, having the same beginning, e.g. `<title>Lorem Ipsum</title> & <title>Lorem Ips</title>` so less easy to tell apart for a human reader.
So the ultimate solution is that I have a text file available from which I will select blocks of text of the correct length from random start points in this block of text. (I'm thinking of a spot of Marcel Proust just to be pretentious)

And if someone can do this as a perl one-liner, I'll forever be in awe.
Take it that the target elements are always on a line on their own and that the elements only contain text, no child-elements or attributes.

Comment: Just to clarify, you already are happy with the outer regex, and are looking for something that could replace your `$content =~ s/\S/*/g;` that instead sets `$content` to an equal length text chosen at random from a source file?

Comment: A security consideration: If the replacement *lorem ipsum* has the same length as the sensitive original, then the replacement still carries sensitive information. A more secure solution would only emit replacement in discrete lengths, e.g. `0–14 → 7, 15–50 → 30, 50–100 → 75, …`.

Comment: Neil, your clarification is correct and far clearer.

Answer (score 4):

OK, here is a proper way to do this, with an XML parser and all, in a (very!) long line:

```
perl -MText::Lorem -MXML::Twig -E'$t= Text::Lorem->new; XML::Twig->parse( twig_roots => { PARA => sub { $l= length $_->text; $_->set_text( substr( $t->words( $l), 0, $l)); $_->flush} }, twig_print_outside_roots => 1, keep_spaces => 1, $ARGV[0])' myfile.xml
```

Going the regex way:

```
perl -MText::Lorem -p -E'BEGIN { $t= Text::Lorem->new; } s{<PARA>(.*)</PARA>}{$l=length $1; "<PARA>" . substr( $t->words( $l), 0, $l) . "</PARA>"}eg' myfile.xml
```

use `-i` if you want to change the file inplace

In both cases, since Text::Lorem does not allow to specify the number of characters of the generated string, I generate a (longer) string of words, then take the substring of the proper length. I suspect you could use `$l/2`for the number of words generated and it would still work OK.